# Using \subimport inside \newcommand

Tags: macros, import

I am using the command `\subimport` and I am very happy with it. However, it doesn't seem to work when I use it inside a `\newcommand` environment.

My file structure is as follows:

```
./main.tex
./Macros/macros.tex
./Macros/Submodules/stringdiagrams.tex
./Macros/Submodules/symbols/somefile.tex
```

`./main.tex` is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{tikz}

\import{Macros/}{macros}

\begin{document}

$\MyInlineFigure$
$\test$
\end{document}
```

My macros are written in a modular style, and every macro submodule is called from `./Macros/macros.tex`, that looks as follows (it is a one-line file for this MWE):

```
\subimport{Submodules/}{stringdiagrams}
```

The file `./Macros/Submodules/stringdiagrams.tex` contains some commands to display `tikz` figures in an inline environment. These files are kept in the folder `./Macros/Submodules/symbols`. `./Macros/Submodules/stringdiagrams.tex` looks as follows:

```
\newcommand{\MyInlineFigure}{ 
   \subimport{symbols/}{somefile}
}

\newcommand{\test}{
    \begin{tikzpicture} [scale=1,transform shape]
        \node [fill=red] (mult) at (0,0) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
```

Finally, `./Macros/Submodules/symbols/somefile.tex` is just

```
\begin{tikzpicture} [scale=1,transform shape]
\node [fill=red] (mult) at (0,0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Theoretically, the commands `$\MyInlineFigure$` and `$\test$` should produce the same output, and I should see two red squares. However, when I try to compile LaTeX cannot find `somefile.tex`.

If in `./Macros/Submodules/stringdiagrams.tex` I replace `\subimport{symbols/}{somefile.tex}` with 
 `\input{Macros/Submodules/symbols/somefile.tex}` then everything works.

If in `main.tex` I comment out `$\MyInlineFigure$` then it compiles and correctly shows a red square, proving that

- `\subimport` is able to reach `./Macros/Submodules/stringdiagrams.tex`
- The problem is not `tikz`.

In the end, it looks like `\subimport` is not working when I call it inside a `\newcommand`. Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: It's very difficult to answer this question in the present form. You know your setup, we don't. Can you please add a simple example starting from `\documentclass` up to `\end{document}`?

Comment: I edited my question, now it is a MWE. You can just copy-paste the contents of every file ad arrange them in the same file hierarchy I gave and the problem should be reproducible. Thanks, Fab –